# Where is xdebug config on homebrew httpd/php?

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, config, xdebug

I am working on MacOS High Sierra and have httpd 2.4 and php 7.1 installed via homebrew. I have `php.ini` file in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini` (with extra files in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d`, including `ext-xdebug.ini`.

This `xdebug.ini` contains the following:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idekey=INTELLIJ
```

If I run on command line `php -i |grep xdebug`, I get all the xdebug settings, including the ones above.

Yet, if I put a php file into the web root with `phpinfo()` in it and access it via the browser, I get the following (among other):

```
xdebug.remote_enable = false
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = _www
```

Where are these values set? I can't find any other config file anywhere.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that apache uses the same PHP as you see in console?

Comment: Check the top table of `phpinfo()` output -- it will tell what php.ini and other config files used. Very likely that you have different php.ini for CLI and Apache. it also possible that you have different PHP installations (version0 used in both environments.

Comment: @LazyOne That was my thought too. However phpinfo() reports that it uses the ini file I indicated above in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was silly of me.  After updating php.ini, I restarted apache, but I didn't restart php-fpm.  Naturally, as the php process was still running, it had cached the settings.  After I restarted php-fpm (`brew services restart php71`) the new settings were picked up and debugging now works as expected.